# Export entire Oracle schema to ASCII and import into DB2

Tags: oracle, db2, import, export

I'm looking for a solution to export a number of schemas from Oracle to ASCII or other flat file format. The data then has to be read by DB2 import. Does anyone know the what oracle export commands would give me full schema export to ASCII on a Unix platform. My testing database is about 30GB in size. I would have to run this via command line on the box.

Comment: Google SQL Unloader.

Comment: Another option to consider is the [IBM Database Conversion Workbench](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=05901c97-75b2-47a1-9c32-25f748855913)

Comment: The IBM Database Conversion Workbench tool is very helpful at generating the required scripts. Thank you.